# Einstien Recommendations API not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein

I am trying to use einstein recommendations collect tracking API.

I am referring to https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/pb-collect-tracking.html documentation.

But when I try the first code from postman , it given me

> Error 403 forbidden.

Can you please help me with it?

```json
{
    "payload": {
        "title": "nto",
        "url": "",
        "referrer": "]",
        "user_info": {
            "email": "abc@gmail.com"
        }
    },
    "user_id": "",
    "session_id": ""
}
```

Comment: what is the endpoint you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You need install and configurate Marketing Cloud Data and set the endpoint and set the MID

[image: Marketing Cloud Connector Settings]